# Geoserver strange inverse polygon rendering

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wms, rendering

I found strange behaviour of rendering one particular polygon on Geoserver. Red polygon in the [link](http://geoserver.geof.unizg.hr/geoserver/karlovac/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=karlovac:tmp_test_pavel&styles=&bbox=-180.0,-87.0,180.0,77.72&width=721&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers). If you compare SHP data from [ZIP file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6591996/layer.zip) in some desktop software like QGIS and rendering from Geoserver, you can see that Geoserver renders that polygon differently.

I am trying to find a reason why this one polygon is wrongly rendered on Geoserver. Does anybody know why this is happening?

I have tested it with Geoserver 2.4 and Geoserver 2.5.1 and data is stored in PostGIS not in SHP.

Comment: Which GeoServer version?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Works for me with GeoServer 2.6 from your shapefile. Could you repeat the test? Publish the shapefile first with your 2.5.1. If it is OK then the difference comes from shp <-> PostGIS. If also the shape shows the issue, test with 2.6 as I did. If it fails for you even it is OK for me then there is something odd but interesting going on.

Comment: I can repeat your issue with GeoServer 2.5.2. Version 2.5.x is still in maintenance so you can write to geoserver-users mailing list and after the feedback make a ticket to bug tracker. Fast fix seems to be to update to version 2.6.

Comment: @user30184 I confirm. I had Geoserver 2.4 which showed the strange behaviour. Now I updated to 2.6 and the problem is gone!

Answer (score 1):

You might run into a problem crossing the +-180°E border in EPSG:4326.

Some points may be rendered at the wrong side, shifted off 360° horizontally.

This is how it should look like:
[image]

Cropping the data to +-179.9 °E might solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried to put that polygon under 180 border but the same thing happens. I think there is some problem with polygon ring orientation but I am not sure.

Comment: Shapefile is valid. There is one ring self-intersection but it is in another polygon.